# How can I launch an external class outside the originator JVM without invoking Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)?

Tags: java, runtime

I mean someting conceptually similar to Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...) but which allows to invoke directly the class without calling exec("java -classpath $currentClasspath my.class.name")...

Just to notice that tools.jar has an useful java class for compiling specifically java sources, there is something similar for executing directly java classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] args = {"foo", "bar"};
my.pkg.MyClass.main(args);
```

Of course, you have to make sure that `my.pkg.MyClass` is on your classpath at compile time and build time.

Comment: Not so easy, I need to isolate the OpenGL thread otherwise inherited

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JAR and you know the API, you can call new on any class and run them as if they were your own. I am not sure what you are asking here. Of course main is just another method of a class, albeit a static one.
Calling exec starts the program in another process, which gives you certain benefits. You might be able to call main in another Thread if desired.
Maybe a little more detail would be good.

Comment: I need to isolate the OpenGL thread otherwise inherited by the invoker class, creating a new one for the invoked class in another JVM process